# Exit code 1 in AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I am trying to publish an application to AWS Elastic Container Service(ECS). I am using the ECS CLI to compose my docker-compose file. There are 2 Docker components. A web container(Flask application) and a server container(NGINX). When just the web container runs all is ok but when I run the server I always get Exit code 1.

*docker-compose.yaml*

```
version: "3"

services:
    web:
        image: 131099/generateme
        expose:
            - 5000
        logging:
            driver: awslogs
            options: 
                awslogs-group: generateme
                awslogs-region: eu-west-2
                awslogs-stream-prefix: web
    server:
        image: 131099/generateme-server
        ports:
            - 80:80
        environment:
            - DOCKER_PROVIDER = ecs
            - DEBUG = true
        depends_on:
            - web
        logging:
            driver: awslogs
            options: 
                awslogs-group: generateme
                awslogs-region: eu-west-2
                awslogs-stream-prefix: server
```

*Dockerfile 131099/generateme-server*

```
FROM nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

*nginx.conf*

```
upstream generateme {
    server web:5000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://generateme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

Any ideas why the exit code is 1? I have checked the logs and it says:

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "web:5000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:2
```

Shouldn't the web container be up first before the server because of the `depends_on` property?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot the `--enable-service-discovery` flag for `ecs-cli`.

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-servicediscovery.html) for step by step, but basically when you bring a service up use that flag.

```
ecs-cli compose --project-name generateme service up --private-dns-namespace generateme --vpc vpc-xxxxx --enable-service-discovery
```

Comment: I follow [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-ec2.html) and here the flag was never used. What is the purpose of service discovery?

Comment: It allows service to discover each other by their name. So `server` should be able to find `web`.

Comment: I used the command `ecs-cli compose -f docker-compose-aws.yml service up --private-dns-namespace generateme --vpc vpc-XXXX --enable-service-discovery --create-log-groups --cluster-config generateme --ecs-profile generateme-profile` to try out what you said but it says `container_name is a required field when using SRV DNS records`. The vpc I am using is one create by following the documentation for setting up ECS. Any ideas where should I add the container names because they are written in the docker-compose file?